# StateMachinePersister is not using the StateMachineContext, extendedState's variables are missing

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, redis, spring-statemachine

I'm using **StateMachinePersister** to persist/restore state machine instances using **Redis**, I restore a state machine and set the **extended state variables**, and persist it. When I restore it later, the extended state variables are missing.

I debugged the **AbstractStateMachinePersister**'s restore method, **the context read holds the extended state variables**, but **the returned state machine doesn't**.

Comment: The restore method in AbstractStateMachinePersister calls resetStateMachine, which in turn populates the ExtendedState variables correctly. The issue could be in your logic, but the source code clearly shows that ExtendedState is being restored. (stateMachine version 2.x source code)

Comment: I looked through the source code and I found the reason, I had the spring dev tools dependency, which makes use of a different class loader and as resulted .getClass check is always false and the variables are never set.